# Jupyter notebook not initializing correctly without error message

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I am having trouble with Jupyter Notebooks (with Anaconda) on a Windows 10 PC from work.
Yesterday I left the laptop running a little script on a Jupyter-Notebook, forgot to check it and **it turned off due to battery**.
Today, when I open Jupyter-Notebook I cannot use it at all. Here I share some screenshots.

The CMD output when launching Jupyter-Notebook (some info deleted since its a corporate pc, such as user).
[image: The CMD output when launching Jupyter-Notebook]

The "landing page"
[image: The "landing page"]

When I create a new python file.
[image: When I create a new python file.]

As you can see, no error message is displayed on the cmd but the application is useless. I cannot see any existing documents or browse folders to open anything. When I start a new file it just stays in "about-blank".

I would need some help to get this working again, thanks a lot in advance!

**update**
When in firefox I go to the console I find that the error is generated by cookie config. It says something like

> "Some cookies are making an incorrect use of recommended attribute
> "SameSite" The cookie "username-localhost-8888" will be rejected soon
> because it has the attribute "<SameSite" set to "none" or an invalid
> value without "secure".

I have not yet found how to change this.

It also says

> Uncaught TypeError: "#element".tooltip is not a function

Comment: what does the tab's title mean?

Comment: "Nueva pestaña"? It's "New tab", in spanish.

Comment: have you update jupyter recently

Comment: I did not update anything recently, at least not manually. I was thinking that maybe the company did some system updates that might conflict with Jupyter, but I am not really aware of that nor how to check it.

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/546  this would help if the response Content-Type is text\plain'

Comment: The error is generated by cookie config. It says something like
"Some cookies are making an incorrect use of recommended attribute "SameSite" 
The cookie "username-localhost-8888" will be rejected soon because it has the attribute "<SameSite" set to "none" or an invalid value without "secure". 
I have not yet found how to change this.

Comment: It also says 
Uncaught TypeError: "#element".tooltip is not a function
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8888/tree?token=5.. etc..

Comment: 1. Have you tried clearing your cookies&cache? 2. Have you tried updating Jupyter?

Comment: 1. I did try that. Didn't work.
2. Do you mean from Anaconda Navigator?